# Can I use variables declared in modifiers in my function?

Tags: solidity

Given the below code, can I use a variable defined in a modifier (ie `_organization`), in my function? It's not compiling now but wondering if there is any way to do this?

```
modifier onlyCEOOrCOO {
     Organization memory _organization = organizations[addressToOrgId[msg.sender]];
     require(
       msg.sender == _organization.cooAddress ||
       msg.sender == _organization.ceoAddress
     );
     _;
   }

function something () external onlyCEOOrCOO {
    // is _organization available here? 
    // If I had used storage instead of memory can I update _organization here?
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's test it out!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ModifierTest {

    address public owner;

    struct myStruct {
        uint256 fancyVar;
    }

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier myFancyModifier {
        uint16 a = 314;
        myStruct memory b;
        b.fancyVar = 159;
        _;
    }

    function myFunction() external myFancyModifier {
        uint16 c = a * 2;
        uint16 d = b.fancyVar * 3;
    }
}
```

The contract above yields the following errors when running `truffle compile`:

> DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
>           uint16 c = a * 2;
>
> DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
>           uint16 d = b.fancyVar * 3;

For both storage and memory, you cannot cross-use modifier variables in functions.